# NSURLSession client side authentication - choose certificate out of list

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, macos

I'm using NSURLSession to sent https requests to server. some connections require client side authentication, So I've implemented the following method

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession*)session
   didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge*)challenge
     completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition,
                                 NSURLCredential* credential))completionHandler {
  if (challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod ==
      NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate) {
...
```

Than I call the following method to get the identity our of the server list of accepted issuers:

```
status = SecItemCopyMatching(dict, (CFTypeRef*)&identityRef);
```

Than I get a certificate out this identity.

```
status = SecIdentityCopyCertificate((SecIdentityRef)identityRef, &certRef);
```

However, if the there's more than one matching certificate so I want to be able to trigger a popup window (like this Windows example), so that the user can choose from :

[image]

How can I display each certificate represented by a subset of selected fields in a popup using objective-c/swift?